# How to remove the label No carrier needed in Shipping page in Prestashop1.6 and how to add vertical scroll in admin left menu

Tags: css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

How to remove the label No carrier needed in Shipping page in Prestashop1.6 [image]

Also 
How to add vertical scrolling in left side menu in Admin side (back office )of Prestashop1.6- Which tpl file I must edit to add the scrolling for the left menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove label edit/remove line 50 in `themes/yourthemefolder/order-carrier.tpl`.

```
{if isset($isVirtualCart) && $isVirtualCart}
    <p class="alert alert-warning">{l s='No carrier is needed for this order.'}</p> // edit or remove this line
{else}
```

The simplest way to add vertical scrolling is to edit the `youradminfolder/themes/default/css/admin-theme.css`, find `#nav-sidebar` and add `overflow-y: auto;`.

Comment: When i added the overflow-y: auto;. then  my sub menu disappear   that is when i hover the submenu it disappears so what to do , So this cant be a solution