# How to make the left menu to be scrollable In Prestashop 1.6.3

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I have so many menus for my super user for my prestashop 1.6.3 Admin panel,As so many modules are used it creates Menus and submenus  which are needed ,
So I want the left menu to be made scrollable.Which tpl or file I need  to edit to do the change for this purpose
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the label No carrier needed in Shipping page in Prestashop1.6 and how to add vertical scroll in admin left menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582011/how-to-remove-the-label-no-carrier-needed-in-shipping-page-in-prestashop1-6-and)

Answer (score 1):

The file you're looking for is located here: `adminXXX/themes/default/template/nav.tpl`

But the `<nav>` id is `nav-sidebar`, so it might be easier just to play with CSS.

Comment: I added overflow-y: auto to the  nav-sidebar  the scroller appears  but the  problem is that when I hover the menu which  have submenus it does not appear , the submenu does not appear So what to do ?

Comment: Meddling with the CSS might have effects on how the JS manages the submenus. I'm not a CSS expert so I can't do much more than indicating where to do your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#nav-sidebar{
    position: absolute !important;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

at `/admin/themes/default/cssadmin-theme.css`